# php methods instead of functions

Tags: php, function, methods

Im pretty new to php and I am wondering about the usage of functions. For example you have to write

```
array_push($my_array,"foo")
```

instead of

```
$my_array->push("foo")
```

It doesn't really hurt but I feels kind of wrong to me... I guess it's because php wasn't oop right from the beginning. But I'm wondering why there is no method implementation jet? I also wanted to ask if there is some kind of "upgrade library" witch provides that?

Comment: OOP uses methods in classes; procedural code uses functions..... if you had a $my_array object that was an instance of a class that had a push() method, then you could do the latter... if you want to write such a class, there's nothing to stop you doing so.... or consider [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php), the Standard PHP Library, which is the "upgrade" library you're asking about

Comment: Why would you want to create a object for arrays just so you can add another element at the end? Maybe this feels more natural for you: `$my_array[] = "foo"`

Comment: @Layne - why indeed, except look at SPL that does exactly this, and has some real benefits to go with it

Comment: The method is called [`->append()`](http://php.net/arrayobject.append) in PHP for the `ArrayObject`.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at the SPL. Is there anything like ->append() for strlen() ?

Comment: There have been some attempts at creating string (and integer and Boolean) objects in SPL, but they're not good, and unlikely ever to be used much..... if you need a pure OOP language with objects and methods for everything, you don't use PHP

Comment: SPL provides a series of specialised object types such as queues, dlls, heaps, etc.... it's intended to supplement PHP, not to give you an automatic switch to writing Java code using PHP

Comment: Basically you can also create your own helper class which contains all common function required of your application. For example if you are going to do above with an helper class you can do like
$helperClassobject->arrayPush($my_array,'element');
And write the definition of this function in your class. 
Just a Suggestion !